# Android addListenerOnButton issue

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create an application with 5 buttons on the main page. For some reason the ListenerOnButton is not working and the app will close before showing xml buttons layout.

Here's my MainActivity:

```js
public class MainListActivity extends Activity {

  ImageButton news;
  ImageButton weather;
  ImageButton counter;
  ImageButton fakoi;
  ImageButton gyalia;
  ImageButton uvindex;

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);

  addListenerOnButton();

 }

   public void addListenerOnButton() {
         news = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.news);
         weather = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.weather);
         fakoi = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.fakoi);
         gyalia = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.gyalia);
         uvindex = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.uvindex);
         
         news.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

             @Override
             public void onClick(View arg0) {

                 Intent intent = new Intent
                         (getApplicationContext(), MyOrasisNews.class);
                     startActivity(intent); 
             }
         });
         weather.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

             @Override
             public void onClick(View arg0) {

                 Intent intent = new Intent
                         (getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                     startActivity(intent); 
             }
         });
         gyalia.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

             @Override
             public void onClick(View arg0) {

                 Intent intent = new Intent
                         (getApplicationContext(), GyaliaActivity.class);
                     startActivity(intent); 
             }
         });
        fakoi.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

             @Override
             public void onClick(View arg0) {

                 Intent intent = new Intent
                         (getApplicationContext(), FakoiActivity.class);
                     startActivity(intent); 
             }
         });
        uvindex.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

             @Override
             public void onClick(View arg0) {

                 Intent intent = new Intent
                         (getApplicationContext(), UvMainActivity.class);
                     startActivity(intent); 
             }
         });
     }
}
```

And this is the xml file

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/db1_root"
     android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
   
  <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
 
        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:weightSum="1"
            android:layout_weight="0.5">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.5">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/news"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/homebg"
                    android:gravity="center|bottom"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    android:singleLine="false"
                    android:text="News"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/news"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.5">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/weather"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/homebg"
                    android:gravity="center|bottom"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    android:singleLine="false"
                    android:text="Weather"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/weather"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </TableRow>
 
        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:weightSum="1"
            android:layout_weight="0.5">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.5">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/uvindex"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/homebg"
                    android:gravity="center|bottom"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    android:text="Uv Index"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/uvindex"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.5">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/fakoi"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/homebg"
                    android:gravity="center|bottom"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    android:text="S Fakwn"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/sfakon"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </TableRow>
 
        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:weightSum="1"
            android:layout_weight="0.5">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.5">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/gyalia"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/homebg"
                    android:gravity="center|bottom"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    android:text="S gyalion"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/sgyalion"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
          
        </TableRow>
 
    </TableLayout>
     </LinearLayout>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: you defined `Button`s in your xml but you are trying to cast them to `ImageButton`. change type of your `ImageButton`s to `Button`.

Comment: Could you provide the error logcat that you get please?

Comment: Thank you  Mohammad Rahchamani it was that easy :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you defined `Buttons` in your `xml` but you are trying to cast them to `ImageButton`. change type of your `ImageButtons` to `Button`.

Answer (score 0):

You try to cast Button to ImageButton.
In your XML file change the Button to ImageButton or in your activity change the ImageButton to Button.